# PHP form not writing to sql

Tags: php, sql, forms

Help, i've been stuck with this issue for a while now. This php registration code that i am following would not work. after submitting the form, the code should write to an sql database, but it won't. please help. thanks. the file name of the php process is registration-process2.php

```
        <?php

        require_once('functions.inc');

        if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                die(header("Location: register.php"));
            }

        $_SESSION['formAttempt'] = true;

        if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
            unset($_SESSION['error']);}

        $_SESSION['error']=array();

        $required = array("lname","fname","email","password1","password2");

        //Check required fields
        foreach ($required as $requiredField) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$requiredField])||$_POST[$requiredField]=="") {
            $_SESSION['error'][] = $requiredField." is required.";
            }
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^[\w .]+$/',$_POST['fname'])) {
            $_SESSION['error'][]="First Name must be letters and numbers only.";
            }

        if (!preg_match('/^[\w .]+$/',$_POST['lname'])) {
            $_SESSION['error'][]="Last Name must be letters and numbers only.";
            }

        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $_SESSION['error'][]="Invalid e-mail address";
            }

        if($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) {
            $_SESSION['error'][]="Passwords don't match";
            }

        //final disposition

        if(count($_SESSION['error']) > 0) {
            die(header("Location: register.php"));
            } else {
                if(registerUser($_POST)) {
                    unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
                    die(header("Location: success.php"));
                    } else {
                        error_log("Problem registering user: {$_POST['email']}");
                        $_SESSION['error'][]="Problem registering account";
                        die(header("Location: register.php"));
                        }
                    }

        function registerUser($userData) {
            $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
            if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                error_log("Cannot connect to MySql: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
                return false;
                }
            $email=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

            //check for an existing user
            $findUser="SELECT id from Customer where email = '{$email}'";
            $findResult=$mysqli->query($findUser);
            $findRow=$findResult->fetch_assoc();
            if (isset($findRow['id']) && $findRow['id'] != "") {
                $_SESSION['error'][]="A user with that e-mail address already exists";
                return false;
                }

            $lastName=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
            $firstName=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);

            $cryptedPassword=crypt($_POST['password1']);
            $password=$mysqli->real_escape_string($cryptedPassword);

            $query="INSERT INTO customer (email,create_date,password,last_name,first_name) VALUES ('{$email}',NOW(),'{$password}','{$lastName}','{$firstName}')";

            if($mysqli->query($query)) {
                $id=$mysqli->insert_id;
                error_log("Inserted {$email} as ID {$id}");
                return true;
                } else {
                    error_log("Problem inserting {$query}");
                    return false;
                    }

            } //end function registerUser

        ?>
```

and the html code.

```
<form id="userForm" method="POST" action="register-process2.php">
```

Comment: Please mention specifically where you stuck. are you getting data in `$_POST` array?

Answer (score 0):

### You are running into scope issues.

See this function ..

```
function registerUser($userData) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
```

The constants `DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB` are not accessible inside here. You need to pass them as parameters and never use the `global` keyword here.